# syntax errors in C++

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I'm new in c++. my friend just gave this code to me but it doesn't work and sends many syntax errors like : error C2146,error C2734,... which I'm not familiar so I thought it should be better to ask stack overflow.
pixel.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"a.h"
using namespace std;
extern const unsigned uint_8 microsoftSansSerif_8ptBitmaps[];
extern const unsigned FONT_INFO microsoftSansSerif_8ptFontInfo;
extern const FONT_CHAR_INFO microsoftSansSerif_8ptDescriptors[];
int main() 
{
    getchar();
}
```

a.h :

```
// Font data for Microsoft Sans Serif 8pt
const unsigned uint_8 microsoftSansSerif_8ptBitmaps[] = {
    0b11110000, 
    0b00010000, 
    0b00101000, 
    0b00101000, 
    0b01000100, 
    0b01000100, 
    0b01111100, 
    0b10000010, 
    0b10000010, 
};
const FONT_CHAR_INFO microsoftSansSerif_8ptDescriptors[] = 
{
    {7, 0},         // A 
};
const FONT_INFO microsoftSansSerif_8ptFontInfo =
{
    2, //  Character height
    'A', //  Start character
    'A', //  End character
    2, //  Width, in pixels, of space character
    microsoftSansSerif_8ptDescriptors, //  Character descriptor array
    microsoftSansSerif_8ptBitmaps, //  Character bitmap array
};
```

errors :

```
a.h(2) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
a.h(2) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'microsoftSansSerif_8ptBitmaps'
a.h(3) : error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'
a.h(3) : error C2146: syntax error : missing '}' before identifier 'b11110000'
a.h(4) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the error message ( at the same time it's good to read it, try to understand it once, it's sometimes 100 times clearer than what you fear). A good practice is to include the minimum code sufficient to reproduce the problem.

Comment: then I get this one : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: Can you provide the line numbers, too?

Comment: Edit your question to indicate the error messages, and which lines they are on.

Comment: Ah, and btw.: `FONT_CHAR_INFO` does not exist as a type, only _FONT_INFO (according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For that you have to include `windows.h`. Furthermore I haven't found a data type called `FONT_INFO`. Can you provide more information about that, too?

Answer (score 2):

Some problems:

1. `uint_8`, `FONT_INFO`, and `FONT_CHAR_INFO` are not declared anywhere.
2. Unnecessarily adding `unsigned` before custom types is an error.
3. Binary literals require compiling in c++11 mode, and a compiler which supports that.
4. To use `getchar`, you need to include `<cstdio>`.
5. Generally, you should put the `extern` declarations in the `.h` file and the definitions in the `.cpp`, not the other way around.

Comment: You forgot to add `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: @arc_lupus What requires windows.h in this code? `FONT_INFO` and `FONT_CHAR_INFO` don't seem to be standard Windows types.

Comment: Maybe he wanted to use `_FONT_INFO` which matches the data (partly) and which is defined in `windows.h`

Comment: @arc_lupus I don't see such a type. Maybe you mean `CHAR_INFO`, but that doesn't match the data (7 is not the unicode code for 'A'), and that type is not related to fonts.

Comment: Ok, I shouldn't do two things at the same time, I am starting to mix stuff up, you're right.